# SharePoint Infopath 2010 development

Tags: infopath

I am new to the SharePoint Infopath 2010 development. What are the required components that I need to install to start with the development.Is it possible in SharePoint foundation server? Can anyone please help me how to start in this?

Answer (score 4):

In order to write any sort of code for your infopath form you will need to install the VSTA.
In the VSTA you can write your code in C# or VB.

The following are the steps to install VSTA :
1)Go to Control Panel and select Add and Remove Programs
2)Select Microsoft Office Professional, Right Click and Select Change
3)Select Add and Remove Features
4)Select Microsoft Infopath and click on the "+" sign
5)An option called as .NET Programmability Support will be present, click on the "+" sign.
6)You will find Visual Studio Tools for Applications(VSTA). Right click on it and select Run from my computer.

A small installation will start installing the VSTA.

After the VSTA is installed you can select Code Editor from the developer tab in the Infopath and begin coding.

For learning basic code behind you can refer to this link : http://panvega.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/how-to-access-infopath-fields-with-codebehind/

Happy Coding

Answer (score 2):

In order to allow the users to add InfoPath Forms Web Parts and Form Template libraries, you are going to require InfoPath Forms Services to be activated, which is part of the Enterprise Features.

See the text and images of the **InfoPath Forms Services support ** section on [this page](http://sharepointchick.com/archive/0001/01/01/sharepoint-enterprise-features-functionality.aspx) to determine if you have it activated.

Another way to tell if its not activated is if you go to design a new form in InfoPath 2010 and you get an error message telling you that Microsoft Office Forms Services is not available.

To activate it on your Farm, execute the following in a SharePoint 2010 Management Shell:

```
Install-SPFeature -path "IPFSSiteFeatures" - force
Install-SPFeature -path "IPFSWebFeatures" - force
Enable-SPFeature -Identity c88c4ff1-dbf5-4649-ad9f-c6c426ebcbf5 -URL siteURL - force
```